# NO pubkey in xubuntu 11.10 when i use apt-get update

Tags: software-sources

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 85753AA5EEFEFDE9
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51AFC9B27331E9C4 thx
```

Comment: why have you got an opensuse repo?  Untick this in your software sources if my first thought...

Comment: thanks a lot men it is going and the error is no more :) how easy i have linux 1.st time so you see it

Answer (score 1):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

The error you see is due to you having added a OpenSuse repository.

Search in Dash for *software sources* and untick the OpenSuse repositories you see in the *Other Software* tab.

Close and the refresh *Update Manager*

Alternatively - from a terminal run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```